# Get all variables of closure

Tags: groovy

How to get all variables defined in closure

```
printVars {

        def date = new Date()
        def str = "ffff"
        metaClass.properties.each {println it.name}
    }
def printVars(Closure cl){

    cl()

}
```

Its return fields of the class. How get vars of closure?

Comment: You have to introspect the AST. local variables are not accessible through reflection, and a smart compiler can remove them if it optimizes the code.

Comment: But why would you want to? Do you have a better example?

Comment: i want to make a persistence execution context for long running process with recovery

Comment: Instead of variables, why don't you use a map? Each variable could be a key/value pair. Then you'd be able to iterate through them.